# "EISA : cannot allocate resource for Mainboard" error on installation

Tags: system-installation

I'm trying to install Linux Ubuntu on my system. I made my self a USB Linux and rebooted  using the usb. The usb was recognized and started and after choosing *Presistent mode / Live Mode*, Linux begin to start until this error:

> EISA : cannot allocate resource for Mainboard

I rebooted and tryed the install option but still got the same error. I rebooted again, with live linux, this time it worked and I was in linux, I restarted to get in the *Presistent mode*, and again the same problem, then tryed *Linux Live* again, it didnt work anymore. I recived the same problem.

I really can't understand what is wrong. Sometimes it works sometimes it does't.

The strange thing is, it worked one time, and I reached the Linux desktop. I just restarted and nothing works again. Has anyone faced this before?

Comment: The `EISA` error is nothing to worry about. The system should still boot. Could you please try to boot with the option `acpi=off` ?

Comment: it was standard set on acpi=off ... should i wait longer when the error show ? because my system did nothin for about 5 min  after posting the error/warning message.. so i rebooted..

Comment: Ok, then i have no idea, sorry. The EISA "Error" occurs on every system, that has EISA support built into kernel, but no EISA support by hardware.

Comment: so. after reinstalling , i saw that the acpi=off is not standard on, it is the first one in the list, but it is not choosed(standard is nothing choosed), and that solved the problem,, thanks alot ! maybe you can post it as an answer :)..  and thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The EISA error is nothing to worry about. The system should still boot. Could you please try to boot with the option acpi=off