# My keyboard doesn't work after a cold boot, works after reboot. ASUS ZenBook 14, it's brand new running 22.04 LTS

Tags: boot, keyboard, hardware

First post, apologies if I've overlooked and broken a rule.

I recently bought an ASUS ZenBook 14 UX425UG_Q408UG and all hardware works flawlessly out of the box with the exception of suspend causing weird issues (which I will either fix separately from this post or live with it), and the keyboard doesn't work after a cold boot. When I turn it on I have to immediately reboot to get the keyboard to work at which at that time it works perfectly until I shutdown entirely. This is every single time. I've looked at all the settings and tried switching to a TTY from the login screen but the keyboard is disabled entirely (other than one of the fn+f# keys working, I think volume down). I checked dmesg and while there are a few errors, there is nothing I know or recognize as related.

/var/log/dmesg : https://pastebin.com/Wb3cQDuE

inxi --full : https://pastebin.com/QFKUaZAm

The back-lighting works but other than the single 2-key function combo for volume down, nothing works until I reboot. Any help would be appreciated. I apologize if this issue is already here somewhere on the site, I searched everything that I knew to search and while I found related posts none of them tackled my exact issue. There were a few that came close with no responses and thus were unsolved.

I'm running 22.04 LTS with the 5.15.0-39 kernel and coming from Arch and Void I keep everything up-to-date pretty regularly.

If this is a duplicate please let me know and I'll remove the post. Thank you.

EDIT #1: ChanganAuto, disabling fastboot did nothing. I rebooted and cold booted multiple times to be sure.

Waltinator, journalctl 0 https://pastebin.com/Se4YdKT1 & journal ctl 1 https://pastebin.com/7rpdYhDV I have no idea how to go about parsing such a massive wall of info in the right way, but I did come across a section that said something like "Warning, multiple definitions of keyboard" or something like that - but it wasn't even yellow or red so I have no idea if that's an error or not. Where do I learn how to parse thousands of lines of info so I can do this myself?

Comment: Disable Fast Boot in UEFI and try again

Comment: After a Boot (keyboard fail], Reboot (keyboard OK) sequence, compare the results of the terminal commands `sudo journalctl  -b -1` and `sudo journalctl  -b 0` (The startup logs from the two boots). See how your keyboard is detected/initialized (or not).

Comment: @waltinator I posted links to the two commands but have no idea how to go about comparing them. There's thousands of lines. I did read through them and found a bit about the keyboard being defined in multiple ways or something like that. No idea if it's even a problem.

Comment: @ChanganAuto fastboot had no effect at all.

Comment: Hi @TexasBaker, If I understand it right, you are using an usb RF keyboard and mouse set on an Asus laptop. I suggest you look for USB legacy in your BIOS settings and turn it on. Some options like turn on your computer might still not work tough. I think it is not the operating system but your computer's own settings that make it so.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["EISA : cannot allocate resource for Mainboard" error on installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51382/eisa-cannot-allocate-resource-for-mainboard-error-on-installation)

Comment: @Wingarmac I've toggled every option in the bios with either zero or negative effect, and I tried the acpi=off option as well which fixed the keyboard issue but disabled the touch-pad and introduced severe lag to the system. Upon reboot it was complaining about not finding an irq for the nvidia card. This is all on the integrated touch-pad and keyboard. I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, or rather one that worked. This post (https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=363163) had the same laptop and same issue - I used their solution and it worked immediately.

I had to add the "i8042.reset" kernel parameter. I don't know for sure what it does, but it worked.